# How to declare an stl::priority_queue with initial data and custom comparator?

Tags: c++, constructor, priority-queue

I need a `priority_queue` for my structs. I want to construct one using both initial data from an array and a custom comparator:

```
class mycomparison
{
public:
    mycomparison(const bool& maxOnTop=false, const int& compField = 0);
    ...
};

mergeRecord initialRecords[N]; // my array
mycomparison(false, field); // my custom comparator

std::priority_queue<mergeRecord, std::vector<mergeRecord>, mycomparison>
    recsHeap(???);
```

On the cplusplus reference, there is an example of how to initialize a `priority_queue` object with a comparator **OR** an array with initial values. How would I do both? I know I could insert them one by one, but this would cost O(nlogn) whereas passing them all at once is O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range constructor for `std::priority_queue` allows you to pass a comparator function in as an optional argument:

```
template <class InputIterator>
priority_queue (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                const Compare& comp = Compare(),
                const Container& ctnr = Container());
```

So just call it like this:

```
std::priority_queue<mergeRecord,std::vector<mergeRecord>,mycomparison>
    recsHeap(std::begin(initialRecords), std::end(initialRecords), mycomparison(false,field));
```

Answer (score 2):

In below example `std::greater<int>` is the compare function and `myints` is an integer array. We can create a priority_queue  `my_priority_queue` as follows:

```
int myints[]= {10,60,50,20};
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> >
                            my_priority_queue(myints,myints+4);
```

In your example:

```
priority_queue<mergeRecord,std::vector<mergeRecord>,mycomparison>
 recsHeap (mergeRecord, mergeRecord+ kWayMerge,mycomparison(false,field));
```

Comment: I saw that example on cplusplus.com, I mentioned I wanted a comparator argument as well.

Comment: @TartanLlama Thanks, that is valid. corrected the answer.